# Terraform issue passing resource to module and depends_on

Tags: terraform

I'm working on refactoring some TF code. I'm using module to keep the code DRY.

This is the `main.tf` for `dev env`

```
provider "vault" {
  address = "http://localhost:8201"
  token   = "something"
}

resource "vault_audit" "this" {
  type     = "file"

  options = {
    file_path = "/vault/logs/audit"
  }
}

resource "vault_auth_backend" "this" {
  type     = "userpass"
}

module "vault" {
  source = "../modules/vault"
  for_each = var.service_type
  environment = var.environment
  db_password = each.value.db_password
  service = each.key
}

module "docker_container" {
  source = "../modules/docker"
  for_each = var.service_type
  environment = var.environment
  service = each.key
  port = "8200"
}
```

Below is the `modules/vault/main.tf`

```
resource "vault_generic_secret" "this" {
  path     = "secret/${var.environment}/${var.service}"

  data_json = <<EOT
{
  "db_user":   "${var.service}",
  "db_password": "${var.db_password}"
}
EOT
}

resource "vault_policy" "this" {
  name     = "${var.service}-${var.environment}"

  policy = <<EOT

path "secret/data/${var.environment}/${var.service}" {
    capabilities = ["list", "read"]
}

EOT
}

resource "vault_generic_endpoint" "this" {
  depends_on           = [vault_auth_backend.this]
  path                 = "auth/userpass/users/${var.service}-${var.environment}"
  ignore_absent_fields = true

  data_json = <<EOT
{
  "policies": ["${var.service}-${var.environment}"],
  "password": "123-${var.service}-${var.environment}"
}
EOT
}
```

I'm stuck on passing to the module `vault/main.tf` the resources `vault_auth`*`backend (also with the depends_on`*`)` and `vault_audit.`

I have tried moving

```
resource "vault_audit" "this" {
  type     = "file"

  options = {
    file_path = "/vault/logs/audit"
  }
}

resource "vault_auth_backend" "this" {
  type     = "userpass"
}
```

To the `vault/main.tf` file, but I get the following error.

```
Error: Get "http://localhost:8201/v1/auth/token/lookup-self": read tcp 127.0.0.1:51550->127.0.0.1:8201: read: connection reset by peer
    with module.development.provider["registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/vault"],
    on dev/main.tf line 1, in provider "vault":
     1: provider "vault" {
```

Comment: The issue seems to not be related to the resource moving but with the provider initialisation. The error is very specific and states that the provider can't connect to the Vault service at the mentioned endpoint.